# How to call php file after javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I'm doing contact form on my portfolio website. I made working PHP form and also working javascript validation but when I tried to add both to work one after another it crash.

**To sumarize I would like to know how to call contactForm.php after the all inputs are valid.**

Here is my JS code:

```js
        function formValidator(){
          const form = document.getElementById('form');
          const name = document.getElementById('name');
          const email = document.getElementById('email');
          const message = document.getElementById('message');
          let errorStatus = true;
        
          form.addEventListener('submit',(e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); // here I stop submiting
            checkInputs(); // here I check validation of inputs
            if(errorStatus == true){ //if its ok I run this
    
              console.log("Its ok")
              var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
              {
                  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;}
              };
              xhttp.open("POST", "contactForm.php", true);
              xhttp.send();
            } 
    
    else{
            form.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'});
            }
          });
        
          function checkInputs(){
            const nameValue = name.value.trim();
            const emailValue = email.value.trim();
            const messageValue = message.value.trim();
        
            if(nameValue === ''){
              setErrorFor(name, "Proszę podać imię");
        
            } else{
              setSuccessFor(name);
            }
          }
        
          function setErrorFor(input, message){
            const formControl = input.parentElement;
            const errorContent = formControl.querySelector('.error-message');
            const alertVisibility = formControl.querySelector('.alert');
        
            errorContent.innerText = message;
            alertVisibility.style.visibility = "visible";
        
            errorStatus = false;
          }
        
          function setSuccessFor(input){
            const formControl = input.parentElement;
            const alertVisibility = formControl.querySelector('.alert');
        
            alertVisibility.style.visibility = "hidden";
        
            errorStatus = true;
          }
        }
```

I added this code:

```
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
      {
          if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;}
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "contactForm.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
```

Here is contactForm.php

```
    <?php
// Get data from form 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'];
 
$to = "piotr.brze95@gmail.com";
$subject = "Nowe zlecenie od " . $name . " z strony MelonStudio";
 
// The following text will be sent
// Name = user entered name
// Email = user entered email
// Message = user entered message
$txt ="Name = ". $name . "\r\n  Email = "
    . $email . "\r\n Message =" . $message;
 
$headers = "From: noreply@demosite.com";
if($email != NULL) {
    mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
}
?>
```

and it doesnt work. I also made some research to find the best way to aproach forms and this is what I ended with. PHP form with JS Validation but I can't combine them.

You can also check this website here: [My Portfolio](https://melon.studio/) and the contact form is in the end of the page.

---

**Update 29.12**

After some code updating I managed to send email correctly.

Here is my JS code that check if there is no error and fetching php file:

```
      e.preventDefault();
        checkInputs();
    
        if(errorStatus === true){
          console.log("Its ok");
          phpFetcher();
          window.location.href = "https://melon.studio/success-page.html";
    
        } else{
        form.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'});
        }
      });
    function phpFetcher(){
form.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    const formattedFormData = new FormData(form);
    postData(formattedFormData);
});

async function postData(formattedFormData){
    const response = await fetch('contactForm.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: formattedFormData
    });
}
```

The problem is that JS doesn't wait for executing the php file and redirecting the website instantly.

Comment: If it crashes, what's the error you get? Give us a clue at least, please.

Comment: @aDyson it just doesn't run my php file. You can check it in console here [My portfolio](https://melon.studio)

Comment: @dzm11, please add the code of contactForm.php

Comment: it seems you have wrong code in contactForm.php.

Comment: I added PHP code but it was fine when it was called by <form id="form" method= "POST" action="contactForm.php">. Its not ok when it is called by JS after validation.

Comment: ```header("Location:index.html");``` this is your problem. You should remove it and should send response for ajax request by ```echo "Your message has been sent"```. In your case, you can return the result of ```mail``` function.

Comment: Let me add the code

Comment: Im not sure if I understand. This line `header("Location:index.html"); ` mean that after executing the code I will be redirected to homepage and this is what I want.

Could you explain it to me please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250720/discussion-between-david-f-and-dzm11).

Comment: You can't redirect from an AJAX/XHR call. The _whole point_ of AJAX is to allow you to stay on the same page in the browser, without needing to post back or redirect, or refresh. If you don't want that, then don't use AJAX.

Comment: @ADyson can you check the updated code I wrote? Now Javascript is calling php file but it doesnt wait for executing it.

Comment: Thanks. `form.addEventListener('click` would make it run as soon as you click anywhere on the form. That doesn't make any sense. You're already handling the form submission earlier...that should be enough

Comment: Also if you want it to wait for the ajax request then you would need to `await phpFetcher()`

Comment: But why are you redirecting after an ajax request? Like u said above, the whole point of ajax is to allow you to stay on the same page without needing to post back, refresh or redirect! If you want to redirect after that, then I'd question whether ajax is really the best approach for sending the data initially

Comment: @ADyson I want to submit form > send it to my email > redirect to succes-page.html
Thats why I want redirection

Comment: Ok well if you want that, I see little value in using AJAX. Just do your validation, and then submit the form normally if it passes.

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location:index.html");`. this is the first issue. You should remove it. The second issue is you didn't send response for ajax call. You should send response for ajax request by `echo "Your message has been sent"`. In your case, you can return the result of mail function.Please add this code in `contactForm.php`.

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers)) {
   echo "Your message has been sent";
} else {
   echo "Enter the valid email address"
}
```